# TypeError when using a directive to apply jQueryUI theme to button with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have the following button:

```
<input type="button" jqButton data-ng-disabled="disableButton" 
       data-ng-click="toggleIsActive(foo)" />
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14608318/1005609), I have created the following directive to apply the jquery `.button()` theme:

```
app.directive('jqButton', function () {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.button();
    };
});
```

I can see that the element in the directive is the correct button when I break on it in Chrome dev tools, but when `.button()` is applied, the following error is thrown:

`TypeError: undefined is not a function`

I am doing anything obviously wrong?

Comment: The directive should be called as jq-button in the html markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element` is either jQuery or jqLite depending on whether or not you load jQuery. None of them have a `button` function. see the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element and http://api.jquery.com/

To avoid the `TypeError` you encounter, make sure to load jQuery and jQuery UI before angular. The `button` function should then be available and you should not receive an error anymore.

Comment: I did have angular registered before jquery and jquery-UI. Now working, thanks.